# show the pdf url to authenticated people on the application

Tags: url, servlets

I'm trying to opening the URL that has the pdf document in the new tab. If I click on 1000 anchor tags then it will display the url in new tab like http://sivls100.eskom.co.za:8080/finalnewnrs/Document.do?method=dt&fn=1000.pdf. But if any person has this URL in the network can see the pdf file. I would like to show the pdf file to authenticated users.I did some investigation and found that we can achieve this by setting authenticated user in attribute like setAttribute and get Attribute. I did some code and it works as long as session valid. My session timeout is 30 min.It will not work after 30 min.

Code:

```
public ActionForward dt(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        Object obj = request.getSession().getAttribute("userDetail");
        String target = new String(SUCCESS);

        if (obj == null) {
            target = new String(FAILURE);
         } else {
            String filename = request.getParameter("fn");
            request.setAttribute("filename", "upload/dt/" + filename);
        }

    return mapping.findForward(target);
}
```

Thank you for any help or atleast for the better design.

Comment: Instead of setting target to `FAILURE`, you have to redirect the user to a login form, and after (successful) login back to the PDF's URL. Btw. `obj` is a terrible name, use `user` or `userDetail` instead.

Comment: Hi my requirement is it must go to the custom error page when user is not authenticated i.e FAILURE and it should go to login page when the session timeout.I did use the code for timeout but when pdf url open in the new tab only new tab is going the login page but current page which has the 1000 anchor tag is still active.I did use the session.invalidate() but current page is not going to login page.when i click on the refresh then only it goes to the login page.

Comment: So i thought may be i should change my design.There is another way like i need to popup warning when session is timeout but it is complicating the process.I used the obj because we have internal users and external users i.e USER and JUSER.So to make it simple i used the obj.

Comment: Session timeout = logout. Unless you have some form of Single Sign-on, but you haven't mentioned that.

Comment: The easiest way of making the session timout is to add the code below: `<meta HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="<%=session.getMaxInactiveInterval()%>; 
              URL=./login/logout.jsp" />`